# Custom Logback Appender not activated

Tags: java, logback, slf4j, lombok, logback-classic

Java 11 and logback-classic-1.2.11 here. I'm trying to write my own custom appender and am following [this Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/custom-logback-appender) to test it out.

My `src/main/java/myapp/logging/CatAppender` appender (on the runtime classpath):

```
public class CatAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {
    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent eventObject) {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }
}
```

My `src/main/resources/logback.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration debug="true">

    <appender name="cat" class="myapp.logging.CatAppender"/>

    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="cat" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

In my `build.gradle` I specify to use logback and Lombok:

```
plugins {
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version '6.4.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation (
        'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.11'
        ,'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.16'
    )
}
```

And then in my Java code I use Lombok to inject an SLF4J logger like so:

```
@Slf4j
public class SomethingDoer {

    public void doSomething() {
        log.info("this should invoke the CatAppender...");
    }

}
```

But when `SomethingDoer#doSomething()` runs, I don't see a `meow` printed to my STDOUT console. Have I wired anything up incorrectly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major miss in that Baeldung article is the fact that you need to call the custom appender's `start()` method, otherwise log messages will not be logged by the `AppenderBase` subclass.

In my case I just call `start()` from inside the CatAppender constructor and everything works:

```
public class CatAppender extends AppenderBase<ILoggingEvent> {
    public CatAppender() {
        super();
        start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void append(ILoggingEvent eventObject) {
        System.out.println("meow");
    }
}
```

FWIW the `start()` is considered an initialization or constructor-level check. You should make sure everything inside your appender subclass is "healthy" enough to begin logging, and only then, call `start()`.

So in the case of my `CatAppender` since its just "meowing" to STDOUT I can do that from inside the constructor. Other, more complicated subclasses will have to figure out when/where its appropriate to activate the appender via `start()`.